# Entity Framework 6 adds additional foreign key with underscore

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm having a trouble with Entity Framework 6.

The Migration generates additional foreignkey with underscore.

I have a table for Person and PersonRelative

**Person Table**

- Id
- Name

**PersonRelative Table**

- Id
- PersonId
- RelativeId (Person type)
- Relationship (Additional Table, to determine what is the relationship
  of the Person to its Relative.)

Using code first the Entity Framework migration adds an additional foreign key for PersonId and it's a Person_Id.

So basically, the **PersonRelative** table has:

- Id
- PersonId
- RelativeId
- Relationship
- Person_Id

This is the generated code:

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.PersonRelatives",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Relationship = c.string(nullable: false),
                    PersonId= c.Int(nullable: false),
                    RelativeId= c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Person_Id= c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Persons", t => t.PersonId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Persons", t => t.RelativeId, cascadeDelete: true)

            .ForeignKey("dbo.Persons", t => t.Person_Id)
            .Index(t => t.PersonId)
            .Index(t => t.RelativeId)
            .Index(t => t.Person_Id);
```

My Model for PersonRelative Entity:

```
public class PersonRelative
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Relationship{ get; set; }




    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int PersonId{ get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Relative")]
    public int RelativeId { get; set; }
    public Person Relative { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Please show the classes in C# code.

Comment: Get rid of [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] on PersonId. Probably not your issue, but not needed on a FK.

Comment: @SteveGreene it actually does nothing, I just get it from another SO post. I should have to get rid of it.

Comment: It also happened to me, after putting "ID" in the name of the table field.

I typed "PersonID" and voila ....

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fixed my issue by adding this code (see code snippet below) to my DbContext OnModelCreating.

With the help of this documentation: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships#configuring-a-composite-foreign-key

Thanks to @Giovanni for pointing me to a right direction.

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
       .HasMany(a => a.PersonRelatives)
       .WithMany()
       .Map(a =>
       {
           a.MapLeftKey("PersonId");
           a.MapRightKey("RelativeId");
       });
```

My Person Relative Class:

```
public class PersonRelative
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Relationship{ get; set; }




    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int PersonId{ get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Relative")]
    public int RelativeId { get; set; }
    public Person Relative { get; set; }

}
```

My Person Class:

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id { get; set; } 
   public string Name{ get; set; }
   public ICollection<PersonRelative> PersonRelatives {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: This can't be right. There's no many-to-many relationship between `Person` and `PersonRelative`. `PersonRelative` *is* the relationship. I suspect something in the `Person` class causes the extra FK, that's why I asked to show the class code.

Comment: @GertArnold, it actually generates a correct CreateTable code in my Migration file and the seed works perfectly fine as well. I can get all the relatives of a specific person using Person.PersonRelatives and loop through on it.

Comment: I removed this [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to override `OnModelCreating` in your `DbContext` and specify your relations manually.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<PersonRelative>()
       .HasOne(p => p.Person)
       .HasForeignKey<int>(p => p.PersonId);          
}
```

Read more about keys and relations here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/fk-constraints

Comment: Not an EF Core question.